# Merge two databases in postgres with different tables

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm absolute new to databases! I've developed a web-app with a postgres database. For evaluating my software, I've done a first field experiment with a fee colleagues. Afterwards there was a lot of bugfixes.

Now I've got a dump after the field experiment. But then I changed my database, renamed two tables, added a few tables and so on. How can I merge my dumped/old database the easy way?

Is there an easy way?

Feel free to ask for some data or everything, that helps.

Greetings,
Tobias

Comment: You should have used a tool like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) or Flyway right from the start

Comment: "I should have used"...but what can I do now!?

Comment: you can "restore" one db `pg_dump -s` over another ignoring the errors, but it will only give you missing relations and indexes, not relation structure changes. In other words this is the only thing you can do "the easy way"

Comment: And anything can be inserted manually....thats not much. Nice. I'll give this a try!

Comment: @VaoTsun I dont hink, that `pg_dump -s` is the right command. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html